# CSS: override a property in li style residing within a class

Tags: css, html-lists

Consider these lines of codes:

```html
<dd class="flt-block-content ">
  <ol>
    <li style="width: 50%;">
      <a href="ref">abc</a>
      <span class="count-wrapper">(6)</span>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 50%;">
      <a href="ref">def</a>
      <span class="count-wrapper">(16)</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</dd>
```

How Can I override the `width` property of all the `li` tags that resides in the class named `flt-block-content` with my custom value?

Second Q: Is the use of `!important` necessary for overriding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an inline style and want to override it, you'll need to use `!important` to do so.

```
.fit-block-content li {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using inlinestyles which have specificity greater than id, class or element. So they would override styles from all 3 of these. So in order to have a default width and then override, you can create a class `default` and assign `width:50%` and a class `override` and assign the override styles

```
li.default {
  width:50%
}

li.override {
  //Override styles
}
```

For your second question on `! important`, it's never a good practice to use `! important` unless required in very specific scenarios